# How to measure upload and download internet speed with silverlight and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to measure  upload and download internet speed with silverlight and ASP.NET MVC between client and server. 
How I think it's need to download/upload a file on the server.

Please help me with this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to recreate [SpeedTest.net](http://www.speedtest.net).  They use Flash, but the concepts should be roughly the same.

If you're referring to ASP.NET MVC because the Silverlight app is hosted on it, I'm not sure it will impact your design.  This assumes that all the speed testing logic and UI is implemented in the Silverlight application.

Here's a good article from Laurent Bugnion on downloading files using WebClient:
http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2008032301.html

That should give you all the information you need to download the file to the client, display a progress bar, and be notified when the download is complete.  Using a fixed-size dummy data file, you can easily calculate the speed based on the size and time to download.  The file should be fairly large but not too large, say 10 - 15Mb.  That will ensure an accurate estimate of speed for both slow and very fast connections.

Uploading will work the same way in reverse.  KrystalWare's SlickUpload component should have all the features you need.

Comment: the biggest problem with downloading files for measuring network speed is the files will be written to hdd. this will make the result bounded by hdd write speed which is roughly 300mbps(assuming platter disk).

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do it is just transfer a file to the client and have it send it back.

What you will need to do is have a file of known size, download it to the client, take the filesize/time to transfer and that is your download speed. Do the reverse process to get the upload speed.

It is a good idea to have a file at least a few MB in size so it can average out the peeks and valleys in the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You realize, of course, that the results of your test will be completely dependent on the internet connection that you are using to run the test. From what I am reading, your really just testing your internet connection, which you can do on various websites, such as www.speedtest.net.